# How to make a page post to another

Tags: asp.net

I recall ASP.NET 2.0 added the ability for a page to post back to another page. I've since never used this feature and have hence forgotten.

Now, googling turns up a bunch of results of different techniques. They boggle the mind.

What's the basic, standard way of posting to another page? Can I not just add an `action` attribute on the `<form>` and point it to another page and also add the `POST method` attribute?

Comment: Have you tried simply as you stated -- changing the action to the page you wish to post to?

Comment: Sorry, I am being lazy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN: [How to: Post ASP.NET Web Pages to a Different Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Set the PostBackUrl property for the control to the URL of the page to which you want to post the ASP.NET Web page.

```
<asp:Button 
ID="Button1" 
PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"
runat="server"
Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: Many thanks. Does this generate a javascript onsubmit for the containing form or a onclick handler for the html button?

Comment: No click handler is created because the page is not posting to itself.  The page will be posted to the new page and events are handled on that new page.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that.

```
<form action="page2" method="POST"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

For buttons, imagebuttons, and linkbuttons, you can set the PostBackUrl property to the url where you want the page to post to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PostBackUrl` property of control. The [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property allows you to perform a cross-page post using the Button control.

```
<asp:Button PostBackUrl="YourPageUrlWhereYouWantToPost" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onload handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(IsPostback)
        Server.Transfer("page2.aspx", true);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647331.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I understand very well, though, that that's an internal transfer from one page class instance to another with a complete transfer of state, i.e. the Form and QueryString property bags without causing an extra round-trip as Response.Redirect (302) does. And I understand it is different from my question or the intention I had when asking my question. But it is related. Thanks much. Nice to think of it this way that this, too, is a post to another page, though not by the client.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - notice the if(IsPostback) you can put any number of conditions and only transfer if a specific client action was taken (with regards to the form). Good luck.

Comment: Neat! I didn't notice that earlier. :-)